# Shell or an awk script to find the occurrences of words

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I request a shell or an awk script that finds out the occurrences of words that have three occurrences of the same letter. Example - arcadias.

thank you.

Comment: We also request some effort from you: what did you try? where did you get stuck?

Comment: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_204.html

Comment: Darn it, it got put on hold just as I was just about to post the strictly functional `cat file | tac | grep . | tac | sed 's/ /\n/g' | while read word; do echo "$word" | sed 's/./& /g' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | grep "^ *3 *" >/dev/null && echo "$word"; done` to see if the OP had some additional requirements he'd like to share :-).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -oP '\w*(\w)\w*\1\w*\1\w*' <<END
I request a shell or an awk script that finds out the occurrences of words that  
have three occurrences of the same letter. Example - arcadias.
END
```

```
occurrences
occurrences
arcadias
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar. +1. It even lists them in the order they appear.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` this prints all words with 3 or more letter in same word.

```
echo "arcadias moron brareri" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {n=split($i,a,"");for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {if (b[a[j]]++>1) print $i } delete b }}' 
arcadias
brareri
```

Comment: You want to use `== 2` instead of `> 1`, or use `break` -- if a word contains 4 of a particular char, you see it printed twice.